# Freeing allocated memory of a nested structure

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I have a nested structure of the format:

```
typedef struct {
    int sensoridentification;
    double time;
    double velocity;
    double acceleration;
} Packet;

typedef struct{
    int sensor_ID;
    int number_of_messages;
    SensorPacket **messages_from_array;
} Node;
```

Already, I have a system in place that will continually allocate memory and add data from stdin to structure members until the string "end" is passed in.

Is there a simple function that I can apply to recursively free the memory that I have allocated to this nested structure, when I receive the keyword "end"?

Comment: Think about how you would iterate this structure. There's your answer.

Comment: Is a `SensorPacket` supposed to be `Packet`... Not sure you're showing the right struct definitions... There's nothing "nested" about these two (as shown)... And "recursion" is probably not your best friend...

Comment: why double pointer?

Comment: How do you allocate memory for this structure? Do you allocate an array for all the pointers and then memory for each `Packet`?

Comment: Why the double pointer in `**messages_from_array`? You need to tell us more....

Comment: You are supposed to respond to suggestions and questions in comments. Especially before you post a new question that contains the very same details you were asked to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    int sensoridentification;
    double time;
    double velocity;
    double acceleration;
} Packet;

typedef struct{
    int sensor_ID;
    size_t number_of_messages;
    Packet messages_from_array[];
} Node;
```

As I do not see any reason for double-pointer you can make your life easier and simple use flexible array members. Only one allocation (and free) will be needed .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with any builtin function that does what you ask, but it isn't complicated as well.

Assuming `int number_of_messages` is the length of `messages_from_array`, you can iterate through it and free each element until you reach `number_of_messages`.